# NestedScrollView not scrollable when below youtube android player in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-nestedscrollview, android-video-player

`bottomsheet.xml`

```
LinearLayout
-- YoutubeFragment
-- NestedScrollView
---- TextView (goes beyond the screen)
```

The textview in the NestedScrollView above is not scrollable if the content goes beyond the screen height.
The bottomsheetbehavior dragging is disabled as follows:

```
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
behavior.setHideable(false);
```

But if I replace the youtube fragment with an image, nested scroll works fine.

Turns out that nested scroll works as long as the youtube player is initializing; once initialized something happens and the nested scroll starts working.

What we're trying to achieve is the same sheet as the youtube android app, where the video being played sticks to the top and the bottom part can be scrolled independently.

Comment: i have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, not yet found a solution.